# How to get source and destination widgets with Eclipse Drag and Drop

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

In my DragSourceListener I receive events of type DragSourceEvent, which has the source widget, but not the destination widget.

In my ViewerDropAdapter I receive events of type DropTargetEvent, which has the destination widget, but not the source widget.

Part of the validation of whether a drag and drop is supported, depends on both the source and destination widgets together.

How can I do validation that involves both the source and destination widget?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to drag between your own controls you could use your own `org.eclipse.swt.dnd.Transfer` type containing any extra information your need (probably based in `ByteArrayTransfer`).

The Eclipse `LocalSelectionTransfer` does something a little like this to allow selections to be dragged between controls.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to drag and drop a widget within the same viewer (like trying to reorder elements by drag and drop, etc), you could use the ***getSelectedObject()*** and ***getCurrentTarget()*** methods in ViewerDropAdapter.

getSelectedObject() - returns the selected object in the viewer, This is the source element being dragged.
getCurrentTarget()  - returns the target object currently under the mouse on hovering over the viewer, which would be the destination upon drop.

You could also override these methods to suit your needs.

You could validate the source and target objects in validateDrop () to check if the drop should be permitted.Note that, target object would be available by default within the validateDrop().

```
validateDrop(Object target, int operation, TransferData transferType)
```